# how to restrict access to page via url in drupal 6

Tags: php, url, drupal, hook

i am building an web store.
the store have 4 steps form like so:
($items['soda/checkout/1'] , $items['soda/checkout/2'] , $items['soda/checkout/3'] , $items['soda/checkout/4'])
each step can be access only if the former steps have been submited.

I want to restrict access so that users cant jump from 1st stage to 3rh 4th...

how can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

Although, you can use value of `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to determine the referrer of current page. But it is not reliable.

Instead, you can store this information in cookies & check the current stage of user & take action accordingly.